# how can I get the value from one particular "row" in my json into my xamarincode?

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am currently working on a code but i get the error "Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue" when I try to get a value from my json on a patricular "row".

I gather the data as a JObject and via httplink so I get the data just fine. But I am having trouble gathering just one of the selected row i chose. This is the code:

```
async void loadPhot ()
    {
        var getItems = await parse.getPhotos ();

        foreach (var moreitems in getItems["results"])
        {
            var Pic = "";

            Pic = (string)moreitems["Image"][0]; //error here. trying to get the first data in the json

            picture.Source = Pic; //picture is my x:name of my image in xaml.

        }

    }
```

The json looks like this:

```
{

"results": [
    {

        "Image": "url"
    },

    {

        "Image": "url2"
    }
          ]

 }
```

Comment: Can you post the json that you get from server?

Comment: Can you post a snipped of your json string ?

Comment: updated now with the json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace

```
Pic = (string)moreitems["Image"][0]; //error here. trying to get the first data in the json
```

with

```
Pic = (string)moreitems["Image"]; //error here. trying to get the first data in the json
```

To get an item at a specific row do:

```
var rows = getItems["results"]; 

int desiredRow = 0;

var itemAtRow = rows.ElementAt(desiredRow);

var imageAtRow = itemAtRow["Image"];
```

Comment: yes, but how can I get a particular row from a json then? for example if i want the json on row 3

Comment: cannot find "ElementAt", gives me red text

Comment: Add a using for System.Linq at the top of your file: using System.Linq;

Answer (score 0):

if you always want the first value, then don't use a loop

```
    var getItems = await parse.getPhotos ();

    // get the value of the first item in the results
    var Pic = (string)getItems[0];

    picture.Source = Pic; //picture is my x:name of my image in xaml.
```

Comment: cannot find "GetValue", and how would I be able to get the json row i want?

Comment: if i remove the [0] on my current code i get the data, but i want to use the data on one particular row

Comment: so if i load the data and have 20 different urls to different images, i want to use the image on row 1 in the json

Comment: foreach is a loop - it will repeat for every item in your results, and each time it loops "moreitems" will contain the NEXT item.  If you only want one specific item, then don't use a loop.

Comment: oh ok, thanks. i thought it was better to loop them all out and then take the particular one. thanks